# Added scenes additively, how to remove some of them?

Tags: unity-game-engine, scene

Is there a way to remove some of the scenes added to a master scene, given that all subsequent scenes have been added additively?

Using Unity 2018.2

Comment: Do you mean in a script during runtime or in the editor?

Comment: at runtime, in the game.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't used `SceneManager.MergeScenes(...)` you can use `SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(...)` and pass it either the sceneIndex, sceneName, or a Scene object.

See: [UnloadSceneAsync API Reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync.html)